# Excel DLookup into access query?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm attempting to setup a DLookup in an Excel macro that looks at the current worksheet and compare the two character code from column I to the access query's results of the same two character code and return a yes/no based on the "Have PerMonths" column.

The query in access is named "HasPerMonths" and has a column called Offer (Two character code) and a column called "Have PerMonths" (Yes/No)

My current version of the dlookup doesn't appear to be picking up anything and returns as empty.
Not sure why or what I'm missing. I normally do Dlookups strictly within Access but in this case I need to try to do it through excel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Code is as follows:

```
public sub Test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Dim PerMonths As dao.Recordset
Dim db As dao.Database
Dim varX As Variant

Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("\\page\data\NFInventory\groups\CID\CID Database\Test Database\CID DailyChecks.accdb")
Set PerMonths = db.OpenRecordset("HasPerMonths")
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
varX = DLookup("[Offer]", "HasPerMonths", "[Offer]= '" & ws.Range("I" & i).Value & "'")

'Once I figure out the dlookup I'll update the loop to pull the Yes/No return 
With ws
    For i = 5 To lrow
     If ws.Range("I" & i).Value = PerMonths.Fields("Offer").Value And PerMonths.Fields("Have PerMonths") = "Yes" Then
             ws.Range("AA" & i) = PerMonths.Fields("Have PerMonths").Value
     End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't that VBA code hosted within an Excel session?  If so, I'm surprised Excel doesn't complain about `DLookup()` because it does not have that function.  Or did you create your own `DLookup()` user-defined function in Excel?  If you want to use Access' `DLookup()` you could do `varX = appAccess.DLookup( ...`  But your situation confuses me.

Comment: You can query Access directly from Excel VBA without needing to spin up an Access Application object (though you're not doing that right now...)

Comment: Try ``PerMonths.FindFirst("[Offer]= '" & ws.Range("I" & i).Value & "'")``

Comment: DLookup does not work on recordsets anyway. Only table and query objects.

Comment: @HansUp yeah this is being run from Excel. Based on other comments looks like I can't do a dlookup. Basically I'm just trying to compare the two character codes between a query in access which has a yes/no field to the excel sheet that has a correlating two character code and pull in the Yes/no from the query.

Comment: @ValNik thanks! I will try this out and let you know if this works for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you use a record set you have to use "FindFirst".